# iPhone "Documents and Data" on certain apps show random numbers

Tags: iphone, storage

I would like to ask about this matter since it has been bugging me out.
Certain apps on my 16gb 6S show random numbers as the amount of their "Documents and Data".
I think this first occurred when I installed and used an app called "Phone Clean". By the way, I'm running the current non-beta iOS version available for the 6S which is 11.4(15F79)
Take a look at my screenshots.

[image: Check out the Facebook app] [image: The thing that bugs me] [image: Even on the Apple Music app!]
<sup>click any image for full size.</sup>

If this doesn't have a solution, I'll probably just back up my iPhone and reset then restore but I would like to see your thoughts about this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you link to this phone clean software you ran? It may have messed up your iCloud so you’d need to fix that rather then wiping the device. Hard to tell without more details but a wipe and reinstall will give you lots more data where the corruption or change happened for sure.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I currently have no WiFi connection to redownload my apps but here's the link of the app I've used: Magic Phone Cleaner by Daniel Anderson